# PHP/Ajax pagination thumbnails

Tags: php, ajax, database, pagination

My main goal is to create a Pagination with photo thumbnails. I have successfully managed to create my own pagination. But the problem is, I know how to use ajax, I just don't know how to apply ajax to it so that it is more user friendly. Can someone help me out, I have been struggling to find an answer to this problem. Below is my code.

```
<?php
  require 'php/connect.inc.php';
  $per_page = 3;

  $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM my_list");
  $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

  $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
  $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;


  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, image_small FROM my_list LIMIT $start, $per_page");
  while($mysql_fetch_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<img src=".'img/uploads/'.$mysql_fetch_assoc['image_small'].">";
  }

  if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){
    for ($x=1; $x <= $pages; $x++){
      echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build an application json you need two things, first a script that returns an appropriate response and the other a client making requests.

This is an example of a script that returns `json`

```
<?php
  require 'php/connect.inc.php';
  $per_page = 3;

  $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM my_list");
  $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

  $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
  $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;


  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, image_small FROM my_list LIMIT $start, $per_page");

  $results = array();
  while($mysql_fetch_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){    
    $results[] = $mysql_fetch_assoc['image_small'];
  }      

  header('Content-type: application/json');

  echo json_encode(array(
    'thumbs' => $results,
    'pages' => $pages,
    'current_page' => $page,
    'per_page' => $per_page
  ));

?>
```

here is a simple client script (javascript using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) for make request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourscript.php?page=1"
}).done(function(data) {
  $.each(data.thumbs, function(thumb) {
    // to something
  });
});
```

finally recommend you do not use `mysql_query` and his associates. read [php.net/mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) is **deprecated**

Comment: It gives me an error "Cannot use [] for reading in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\index.php on line 22"

Comment: my mistake, @kuwame see the change in the line `'thumbs' => $results,`

Comment: Now it is giving me another error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\index.php on line 23"

Comment: How come it is only displaying the text?

Comment: IT is giving me this warnings <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\series\index.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\series\index.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
{"thumbs":[],"pages":0,"current_page":1,"per_page":3}

Comment: yes, ajax responses are text you need build other page for process that responses